# How to rectify the fisheye images rendered by VRay in 3ds max 2016?

Tags: 3dsmax, fisheye

I rendered a lot of images using fisheye camera by VRay. Now I want to process these images, but I need to rectify them at first. Could anyone give me some method about it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use following softwares:
[Adobe Photoshop](https://creative.adobe.com/sv/products/download/photoshop?promoid=61PM825Y&mv=other)
[Adobe Lightroom](https://creative.adobe.com/sv/products/download/lightroom?promoid=2XBSC5JS&mv=other)
[Adobe Aftereffects](https://creative.adobe.com/sv/products/download/aftereffects?promoid=RYGDN4F6&mv=other)

Also if you need tutorials, I recommend to take a look on this guy (**Andrew kramer**) he is amazing I learned a lot from him: 
[VideoCopilot](http://www.videocopilot.net)

I hope this will help you

Regards

Daniel

Comment: Thank you very much! But the images are not captured by camera and I can't choose a lens for them, so photoshop cannot rectify the images well.

Comment: @Dobbie, You can make it look the picture is rendered by a Vray camera I have done that couple of times to save time for stuff I compositing, cause in 3d max it takes such long time to render a camera with certain settings.